# Spark DataFrame action throwing NegativeArraySizeException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In my spark 1.5.0 application I'm trying to process an original `DataFrame` by performing several joins on it.

When I run my successfully compiled jar through `spark-submit`, I'm getting this error whenever I try to perform any kind of action on my `DataFrame` (e.g. `show`, `first`, `count`):

```
at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.getBytes(UTF8String.java:234)
at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.toString(UTF8String.java:827)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificMutableProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregationIterator$$anonfun$generateProcessRow$1.apply(TungstenAggregationIterator.scala:276)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregationIterator$$anonfun$generateProcessRow$1.apply(TungstenAggregationIterator.scala:273)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregationIterator.processInputs(TungstenAggregationIterator.scala:533)
```

When I try to execute the very same code on `spark-shell`, something strange happens:

If I call any action on the created `DataFrame`, I get the same exception, but **only the first time**. 
If I retry calling the same action on the same DataFrame, it will work.

Is this a known issue and does a workaround exist or am I simply doing something wrong?

This is the schema of the resulting `DataFrame`:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- language: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- reccs: string (nullable = true)
```

This is the code I'm using to create my `DataFrame`:

```
  val inputData = sqlContext.table(constants.SOURCE_DB + "." + inputTable).
    select(inputTableId, inputTablItemId)
  val itemDetails = sqlContext.table(constants.SOURCE_DB + "." + constants.ITEMS_TABLE).
    select("item_id", inputTablItemId, "language", "publication_date").
    map(row => (row.getInt(0), row.getInt(1), row.getString(2).toInt, cleanDate(row.getString(3)))).
    toDF("item_id", inputTablItemId, "language", "publication_date")
  import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

  val itemColumn : Column = new Column(inputTablItemId)
  val familyWithDetails = inputData.join(
        itemDetails.select($"item_id",itemColumn.alias("item_family_id"), $"language", $"publication_date"),
        itemColumn === $"item_family_id").drop($"item_family_id")

  val filteredDF = familyWithDetails.groupBy(inputTableId, inputTablItemId, "language").
        agg(max($"publication_date")).withColumnRenamed("max(publication_date)", "publication_date")

  val toBeWritten = filteredDF.join(itemDetails.
    select($"item_id",
      itemColumn.alias("item_family_id"),
      $"language".alias("item_language"),
      $"publication_date".alias("item_publication_date")),
    itemColumn === $"item_family_id" && $"language" === $"item_language" &&
      $"publication_date" === $"item_publication_date"
      ).drop("item_family_id").drop("item_language").drop("item_publication_date").
    groupBy(inputTableId, inputTablItemId, "language", "publication_date").agg(first("item_id")).
    withColumnRenamed("FIRST(item_id)", "item_id").
    withColumn("family_item_id", concat(itemColumn, lit("-"), $"item_id")).
        groupBy(inputTableId, "language").agg(groupconcat($"family_item_id")).
        withColumnRenamed("(GroupConcat(family_item_id),mode=Complete,isDistinct=false)", "reccs")
```

Comment: Can you share the schema of the DataFrame (e.g. using the printSchema function?)

Comment: @AssafMendelson updated my question

Comment: how do you create the dataFrame? Can you share some code?

Comment: @AssafMendelson you have full code

Comment: On first glance it looks fine. I would try with a newer version of spark (even installing it locally) just to make sure this is not something fixed. What I would try to do to debug is perform an action after each stage to see what causes it. In general the error seems to be a serialization issue.

Comment: @AssafMendelson thanks for the hints, unfortunately there's no chance that I can update to a newer version of Spark.